# Memory allocation while using structs in C

Tags: c, struct

When memory is allocated when using structs in C? At declaration or definition or initialization?

```
// Here is declaration
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;

// Here is definition
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(void) {
    //This declares and initializes variable of type MyStruct
    MyStruct ms = {.a=100, .b=120};
    return 0;
}
```

Is Memory reserved when we instantiate the object of corresponding stuct type e.g. declaring a variable MyStruct ms in main function in above case.

Comment: Memory is only allocated when you use the struct to declare variables or to dynamically allocate memory

Comment: There is not memory allocated on the heap, you have an automatic variable here.

Comment: In your example, no memory is allocated, local variables that are NOT pointers are created on the stack.

Comment: As you can see from the above comments, allocation is sometimes used to refer specifically to heap allocation (or dynamic allocation). But all variables need memory which is 'allocated' on the stack or in the global data space.

Comment: At the same time as if it were a primitive type.

Comment: Is it right to say that:
Memory is not allocated during declaration and definition of struct.
It is only allocated when struct is used to dynamicaly allocate memory.
In my case, memory gets allocated each time when the function is called but on stack obviously as 'ms' is a local variable.

Comment: It is very unlikely any memory to be reserved for it. You do not use it so the compiler is very likely to optimize it out

Answer (score 2):

Local variables like `MyStruct ms` in your example are allocated on the stack. Most compilers would reserve space for those variables in their [prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue). i.e. when the stack frame(for `main` function in this case) is constructed.

For more, here is a [good article](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/memory-management-techniques-in-c/) about stack memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Memory reserved when we instantiate the object of corresponding
>   stuct type e.g. declaring a variable MyStruct ms in main function in
>   above case.

That's right, the memory is reserved or allocated when the structure is used. In you example, your `MyStruct` is on the stack, so when the function is called, the respective amount of memory is reserved on the stack to hold your variable.

The compiler uses the definition to calculate the amount of memory used so it knows how much memory to allocate / reserve for your instances of the struct on heap or stack, but it doesn't actually allocate any memory yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating memory at this line :

```
MyStruct ms = {.a=100, .b=120};
```

Before, you are only defining the structure.